# OpenGL understand two viewpoint to see model transformation

Tags: opengl, matrix

There are two viewpoints to understand model transformations,I read from Red book 7th edition,[ Grand, *Fixed Coordinate System* ] and [ Moving a *Local Coordinate System* ].

**My Question is:**

What is the difference between the two viewpoints and when to use them for a specified situation ?

**additional context info:**

I'd like to give some context for you to help me,Or you can just ignore below details.

I understood these two viewpoints in the following way.Think I have following code:
(functions like glTranslatef are deprecated,replaced by math library ,but theory may keep helpful.)

```
//render the sence,and use orthogonal projection
void display( void )
{   
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    drawAixs(4.8f);//draw x y z aixs,4.8 is axis length
    glRotatef(45.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(3.0,0.0,0.0);
    glutSolidCube(2.0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

**From the local coordinate view :**

In this viewpoint,we can understand it like :

[image]

And the current transformation matrix(CTM) is:
[image]

**From global fixed coordinate view :**

In this viewpoint,we can get :

[image]

Comment: Hello, this question is very unintelligible. What is your goal? Do you want to simulate old OpenGL `glTranslate()` / `glRotate()` commands?

Comment: "the order in which the transformations are applied is the opposite of the order in which they appear in the program".. because matrix multiplication works like that and i think this is mostly the only way to do transformations in OpenGL.

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal,the viewpoint you take is the 'global fixed coordinate ',as most people tend to explain it this way .Can you give some help on understand the viewpoint of 'Moving a Local Coordinate'?

Comment: @the swine,sorry for my chaotic question.If we try to explain model transformation with the viewpoint of 'Moving a Local Coordinate' then the translate order is as the order appeared in the program code.So what's the specified situaion these two viewpoints are used and their difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two coordinate systems are just a convention. There is always one global coordinate system, but there may be many local systems. The notion of a local system is only a convention. A general transformation matrix `M` transforms vertices from one space to another:

```
v' = M * v
```

So that `v` is in one coordinate space and `v'` is in another. In case `M` describes position of an object, we say that it is putting vertices from local *object* coordinate frame to the global *world* coordinate frame. On the other hand, if it describes camera position and projection, it puts vertices from the *world* coordinate frame to another local *eye* coordinate frame.

A complex objects with joints (such as humanoid characters, or mechanisms with hinges) may actually have several intermediate local spaces, where the transformations are chained, depending on the structure of the skeleton of the object.

Usually, one uses `object space` where the vertices of the models are defined, `world space` which is a global space where the coordinates can be related to each other, and `camera space` or `eye space` which is space of screen coordinates. But with the introduction of OpenGL 3 shaders, these are completely arbitrary: you can write your shader so that it uses a single matrix that transforms the vertices from object space directly to screen space. So do not worry about coordinate frames, just focus on the task at hand - what it is you want to display and how the objects should be moving (relative to each other or relative to some common reference).

Comment: Thanks.I think I got to do more experiments to understand both viewpoint.